# Conditional Expectation on every non-null atom

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In Resnick, A Probability Path has an exercise which claims that for every random variable defined on a triple $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $\mathcal{G}$  a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathscr{F}$, we have that on every non-null atom $\Lambda$ of $\mathcal{G}$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda)>0$ and $\Lambda$ contains no subsets belonging to $\mathcal{G}$ other than $\varnothing$ and $\Omega$, the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}]$ is constant and
$$\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega)=\int_{\Lambda}X\>d\mathbb{P}/\mathbb{P}(\Lambda).$$
I'm not sure where to start. All I know is that the right-hand side is $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \Lambda)$, can someone help me?

Comment: The characterization of being an atom after "i.e." is incorrect.

Comment: Oh no wonder I've never seen this definition before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable by definition, and therefore it is almost surely constant on the atoms of $\mathcal{G}$. You can see a proof of the latter fact [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24845/a-measurable-function-on-an-atom-is-almost-everywhere-constant).

Let us say that $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega) = c$ for almost every $\omega \in \Lambda$.

Recall that by the definition of conditional expectation, we have
$$\int_G X d \mathbb{P} = \int_G \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}) d \mathbb{P}$$
for all $G \in \mathcal{G}$. Let $G = \Lambda$, then

$$\int_\Lambda X d \mathbb{P} = \int_\Lambda \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}) d \mathbb{P} = c\mathbb{P}(\Lambda).$$

Since $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda) > 0$, we can divide both sides by $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda)$ and conclude.