# $\forall B\in\mathcal{B}\quad X^{-1}(B)=\bigcup_{i}\{A_{i}\mid x_{i}\in B\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Here is a claim that I came across in a book along with its proof that I couldn't follow. I need someone to explain it to me, please.

- $\mathcal{B}$ is Borel set.
- $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(A_{i}\mid i=1;\ldots,n)$ has only finitely many atoms

**Proposition:**
If $X$ is simple function over $\mathcal{F}$ then $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable. Conversely, if $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and if $\mathcal{F}$ is atomic, then $X$ is simple function over $\mathcal{F}$.

**Proof:**

If $\forall i, A_i\in\mathcal{F}$, then for all $B\in\mathcal{B}$:
$$X^{-1}(B)=\bigcup_{i}\{A_{i}\mid x_{i}\in B\}\in \mathcal{F} \mbox{(because the union is finite)} $$.

I couldn't understand why :

$$\forall B\in\mathcal{B}\quad X^{-1}(B)=??\bigcup_{i}\{A_{i}\mid x_{i}\in B\} $$

**my attempts:**

$$\forall B\in\mathcal{B}\quad X^{-1}(B)=\{X\in \mathcal{B}\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in B\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}1_{A_{i}}(\omega)\in B\}$$
Even if I am right, I still can't figure out how: $$\{\omega\in\Omega\mid \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}1_{A_{i}}(\omega)\in B\}=\bigcup_{i}\{A_{i}\mid x_{i}\in B\}$$

Comment: Welcome. How are you defining whether or not $\mathcal{F}$ is atomic? Iirc people take it to mean slightly different things

Comment: Also, what is $\mathcal{B}$, what is the significance of the $A_i$, etc.

Comment: Please check my update.

Comment: Also, what are the $x_i$?

Answer (score 1):

Some clarifications. *This is not a full answer* since your question isn't fully explained, still. See the Wikipedia page on [atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)) in measure theory. I'm not entirely convinced that you're using the standard definition of atom, so I'll recall it here:

> An atom is a measurable set $A$ (most authors take it to be of finite positive measure and so will I) such that if $B\subseteq A$ is measurable then $\mu(B)\in\{0,\mu(A)\}$.

And an atomic measure space is typically defined as one where every set of positive measure contains an atom. If the measure space is sigma-finite, this [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025975/countable-partition-in-atoms) that the measure space has a countable partition into disjoint atoms (of finite measure) modulo a null set. This is also equivalent to being atomic.

In your case, we're dealing with something slightly different. Here, I infer that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is your measure space where there is a distinguished pairwise disjoint family $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n\subseteq\Omega$ such that $\mathcal{F}$ is the sigma-algebra generated by the $A_i$. This space is atomic (if you take $\mu$ finite) (why?) but that isn't the definition of atomic. Now, any simple function $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ is clearly measurable, without us needing to suppose anything further about the measure space (I implicitly equip $\Bbb R$ with the Borel measure algebra and will dispense with $\mathcal{B}$ notation).

We want to prove that any measurable $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ is simple. This is very similar to the fact that any measurable function on a (finite) atom is [almost everywhere constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24845/a-measurable-function-on-an-atom-is-almost-everywhere-constant). With regards to your proof, I have two points to make.

Point 1): The comment "Because the union is finite" is completely unnecessary; any countable union of measurable sets is measurable, by definition of sigma-algebra.

Point 2): You are quite right that: $$X^{-1}(B)=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in B\}$$However we know that $X^{-1}(B)$ is a measurable set, if $B$ is, since $X$ is supposed measurable. You haven't explained what the $x_i$ are... but if the  $\{A_i\}$ are taken to be disjoint, then I can help. If $X^{-1}(B)$ is nonempty, there must then be some $i$ such that $A_i\cap X^{-1}(B)\subseteq A_i$ is nonempty as $X^{-1}(B)$ is measurable. However there are, by disjointness, no measurable subsets of $A_i$ other than $\emptyset$ and $A_i$ itself. Thus, $X^{-1}(B)\cap A_i=A_i$. This is true for any $A_j$ which $X^{-1}(B)$ intersects; thus, either $X^{-1}(B)$ is empty or there are some $\{j_k\}_{k=1}^m$, $1\le m,j_k\le n$, with: $$X^{-1}(B)=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^m A_{j_k}$$I *think* this answers the question you intended, but it's unclear.